# 'module' object has no attribute 'TK'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm a beginner of learning GUI.

My python version is 2.7 and I'm using Windows.

I've searched tkinter in folder there is only one python file which is in `C:\python27`.

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk 

class Electronic_Signature_User_Program(tk.TK):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top",fill = "both",expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Loginpage, Login_Confirm):
            frame = Loginpage(container,self)
            self.frames[Loginpage] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Loginpage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Loginpage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        button1 = tk.Button(self,text="Login_Confirm",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Login_Confirm))
        button1.pack()

class Login_Confirm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        button2 = tk.Button(self,text="Loginpage",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Loginpage))
        button2.pack()


app = Electronic_Signature_User_Program()
app.title('UoL 702 Electrinic Signature User Program')
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the very first class declaration you have `TK` where it should be `Tk`.

Comment: Ha! Thank you so much for responding quick! So it is a stupid mistake  XD.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Btw, when I run this program, it shows "tk" as Tittle. what should I change to change that to other string?

Comment: `app.title('New Title!')` before the `mainloop`